# Why don't any characters sing in the 2nd and 3rd Hobbit films?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, behind-the-scenes, music

Tolkien's books have a lot of songs in them, which sometimes become actual songs *sung by the characters* in the films. The films seems to favor having the characters sing on screen more and more, as the number of songs in each installment seemed to grow as the franchise continued.

In *The Fellowship of the Ring*:

- Gandalf sings "The Road Goes Ever On"
- Aragorn sings "Song of Beren and Lúthien" on Weathertop
- The elves sing a "Lament for Gandalf" [in Lothlórien](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KTzve93tXc)

In *The Return of the King*:

- Pippin sings "The Edge of Night" for Denethor
- <strike>Arwen sing "Arwen's song" (but that was a deleted scene so maybe it doesn't count)</strike>
- Aragorn sings "Elendil's Oath" at the coronation

In *The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey*:

- The dwarves sing "Misty Mountains"
- The dwarves sing "Blunt the Knives"
- The goblins sing "Down in Goblin Town"

In the first *Hobbit* film we hear not one, not two, but three new songs! It therefore seems very strange to me that there is suddenly no singing in *Desolation of Smaug* and none in *Battle of The Five Armies*, especially since the song "Misty Mountains" was so popular. Why don't any characters sing in the 2nd and 3rd *Hobbit* films? **Have the filmmakers commented on the lack of songs in the last two *Hobbit* Films?**

---

<sub>NOTE: I'm asking about songs the *characters* sing (Disney musical style); I'm **not** asking about end-credits songs, or parts of the musical score that feature vocalists, etc.</sub>

Comment: They only had 3 songs, and used them all up on the first film because they didn't know if the film would sell well...

Comment: More seriously: why aren't you counting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_See_Fire ?

Comment: If you're counting deleted scenes, AuJ EE had an extra song.

Comment: @red - I don't think Ed whatshisname is meant to represent a specific character, but not certain.

Comment: @DVK The third Hobbit movie also had an credits song https://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Goodbye

Comment: @ibid - I suppose it's as off-scope as the second film's one, if only character-sung ones are of interest. There's a Les Miserables joke hiding in there somewhere, but i'm too beat to find it

Comment: Aragorn sings "Song of Beren and Lúthien" in FotR (maybe only in the extended, not sure). The song that he sings at the end of RotK is "Aragorn's Coronation" or "Elendil's Oath". (These don't really have such clear-cut names)

Comment: @ibid thanks, fixed it

Answer (score 4):

There are songs in the final two *Hobbit* films.

Bard [sings/recites](https://youtu.be/XxKjrJZ3Is0?t=50) "The Lord of the Silver Fountains" in *The Desolation of Smaug*:

> The Lord of Silver Fountains, the King of Carven Stone, the King Beneath the Mountain, shall come into his own. And the bells shall ring in gladness, at the Mountain King’s return, But all shall fail in sadness, and the Lake will shine and burn.

It should be noted that most of the songs that do appear in the movies are either greatly altered or taken out of context from how Tolkien wrote them. (For example Merry and Pippin's Green Dragon song in *FotR:EE* takes a couple of lines from *A Drinking Song* and a couple of lines from *The Bath Song*.)

Comment: I watched the linked video; no singing to be heard. :-/

Comment: @RedCaio whether or not you consider that singing, the stuff he was reciting was a song.